# Could a Tremere get away with this?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, vampire-the-masquerade-5e

Trying to think of NPC concepts and when doing so, came across a question, although first I'll provide some quick context to hopefully make my issue clear:

These NPCs are a mother and daughter family unit, with the mother being a Tremere vampire and the daughter being an adopted human child.

The story is that her kid was adopted with the idea of trying to find out if raising potential candidates for the Pyramid is more effective than what was currently going on - that if they're trained up to be a perfect candidate from near birth, then they can circumvent the high mortality rate of neonates that the clan had. Her arguing, that this would ultimately be more efficient and less of a potential waste of resources than putting so much time into someone who could not handle life with the clan.

The Tremere claims at least that the kid *doesn't* know the reason for the resultant horrible childhood/training being related to the masquerade and vampires.

My question is, for this plot to work: would this motive/story even fly here? As at all acceptable by vampiric society? Or would this simply be deemed as too much of a masquerade risk by other vampires and, by law, the child have to be killed for that very early on?

Disclaimer: I am aware this could cause complications later on. I'm just trying to figure out if laws-wise, it would have been shut down by other vampires, before any child could even get out of infancy.

Comment: IIRC that's basically how the Giovanni do it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### This is entirely storyteller's discretion

This is completely and totally up to the storyteller and the details of the particular city in question. The main concern would be how the Tremere Regent views it. The Prince would, of course, also get a say, but would probably care much less so long as the masquerade was maintained and the Prince would likely listen to the Tremere Regent so long as they were on good terms.

### There is precedence of lines of ghouls

If I were the storyteller or playing the Tremere Regent I would likely allow it. This is the sort of thing that some Tremere would be interested in experimenting with. It has potentially useful benefits and there is precedence for families of Ghouls, which is vaguely similar. The Tzimisce cultivate families of [Revenants](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Revenant_(VTM)) after all. The Tremere also often groom potential new neonates by having them be long-time ghouls anyway, this would simply start the process earlier.

### Doing it indirectly would work much better

While this plan would probably be accepted by at least a lenient and experimental regent, its worth noting that there are simpler ways of doing it. Having the vampire directly adopt the child creates complications in that parents are expected by society to show up to all kinds of functions in daylight. While a vampire likely has ways to avoid breaching the masquerade while still adopting the child, adding a layer of indirection avoids many problems.

Instead of having the vampire adopt the child, have a ghoul or other thrall controlled by the vampire do so. The ghoul can handle all of society's expectations while the vampire has full control over how the child is raised, directly at night and indirectly through the thrall during the day.